# How to apply slide transition to Outlet in react-router-dom v6?

Tags: reactjs, frontend, react-router-dom, react-transition-group

Below is my attempt, which works fine when simply applying slide-left or slide-right to the Outlet.
But I want to judge according to the order of the routing page, dynamically apply slide-left or slide-right, and then I encountered a problem, the routing pages don't slide as I except,
Sometimes one routing page moves to the left and another routing page moves to the right. It seems that the routing page that is about to disappear still retains the last transitionName

Hope someone can give me some advice

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-noether-78rs5c)